# update query in sql based on condition fro two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to build a update query. My existing code looks like this.

```
update table1 
set data_plan=(select d.data_plan from table1 m,table2 d 
               where m.msidn = d.msidn and m.data_plan!=d.data_plan);
```

**table 1** has columns **msisdn** and **data_plan**, **table 2** also has same columns. I want to update the **table1 data_plan** column depending on some condition which I get through select query. But when I run the code I get this error.

> You can't specify target table 'msisdn1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: UPDATE table1 m INNER JOIN table2 d ON m.msidn=d.msidn SET m.data_plan=d.data_plan WHERE m.data_plan != d.data_plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
update table1 m join table2 d
    on m.msidn = d.msidn 
   and m.data_plan != d.data_plan
   set m.data_plan = d.data_plan
```

Comment: Column 'data_plan' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: i get this erroe when i use your code.Column 'data_plan' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: but since i am dealing with huge amount of data this code is taking a long time. can u suggets me a fater code.

Comment: `JOIN`s are usually as fast as you can get. You should have proper indices though. If you are using MySQL 5.6 then you can use `explain <your query>` to see an execution plan. If you are using 5.5 or lower then you can do `explain select * from table1 m join table2 d on m.msidn = d.msidn and m.data_plan != d.data_plan`. It won't be the exact execution plan as in update but will be close enough to see problems.

Comment: hey,  i have done this for my requirement too,
`update table1 m join table2 d
    on m.msidn = d.msidn 
   set m.data_plan = (select plan from plans where name=d.data_plan);`    but its very slow for huge records like table1 having the 1 lac and table2 having the 2.5 lacs records. Is there any improvement ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
  UPDATE table1 SET m.data_plan=d.data_plan
  FROM table1 m
  INNER JOIN table2 d ON m.msidn = d.msidn and m.data_plan!=d.data_plan
```